# How can I put the scope in a directive to stop loosing it when changing views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My first Angular project and I'm a bit confused. I have a slider defining the scope (i believe), but lose that scope when i switch views.  I am not sure how to get the scope into a directive so both views can access it, which i believe to be the solution.

---

Index.html

```html
<div ng-view></div>

<div id="footerContainer">
        <a href="#data">SWITCH VIEW</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

input.html

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div ng-controller="SomeController">
    <div id="sliderContainer">
      Price: {{price}}
      <div id="mySlider" slider config="sliderConfig" model="price" ng-model="price" class="slider"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

data.html

```html
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
  <div>
    Price: {{price}}
  </div>
</div>
```

---

main.js

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'input.html'
      })
      .when('/data', {
        templateUrl: 'data.html'
      });
  }
]);

myApp.controller("SomeController", function($scope) {
  $scope.sliderConfig = {
    min: 1,
    max: 101,
    step: 10
  }

  $scope.price = 1;

  $scope.setPrice = function(price) {
    $scope.price = price;
  }
});


myApp.directive("slider", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      config: "=config",
      price: "=model"
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var setModel = function(value) {
        scope.model = value;
      }

      $(elem).slider({
        range: false,
        min: scope.config.min,
        max: scope.config.max,
        step: scope.config.step,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.price = ui.value;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When switching views, angular is creating a new instance of SomeController.  You need to persist your 'price' value somewhere so that it may be shared among your main views, for example in an outer (parent) scope, in a context service or otherwise some globally accessible data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you  tried the $rootScope? It's a global variable , so if you set something in rootScope ,it can be accessible through out the app, say for example if you set,
$rootScope.userName , it can be accessible in all views.